# Layer Ordering in leaflet.js

Tags: gis, leaflet

How can I force a new layer added to the map in Leaflet to be the first over the basemap?

I could not find a method to easily change the order of the layers, which is a very basic GIS feature. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A Leaflet map consists of a collection of "Panes" whose view order is controlled using z-index.  Each pane contains a collection of Layers  The default pane display order is tiles->shadows->overlays->markers->popups.  Like Etienne described, you can control the display order of Paths within the overlays pane by calling `bringToFront()` or `bringToBack()`.  `L.FeatureGroup` also has these methods so you can change the order of groups of overlays at once if you need to.

If you want to change the display order of a whole pane then you just change the z-index of the pane using CSS.

If you want to add a new Map pane...well I'm not sure how to do that yet.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-panes

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup

Answer (score 7):

According to Leaflet API, you can use `bringToFront` or `bringToBack` on any layers to brings that layer to the top or bottom of all path layers.

Etienne

Comment: Leaflet has also recently added the setZIndex method that can be used on TileLayer to manually manage the tiles layers order with CSS

Answer (score 5):

For a bit more detail, Bobby Sudekum put together [a fantastic demo](http://bl.ocks.org/rsudekum/5431771) showing manipulation of pane z-index. I use it as a starting point all the time.

Here's the key code:

```
var topPane = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-top-pane', map.getPanes().mapPane);
var topLayer = L.mapbox.tileLayer('bobbysud.map-3inxc2p4').addTo(map);
topPane.appendChild(topLayer.getContainer());
topLayer.setZIndex(7);
```

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged in SO, try to answer it with your own words and if you fell necessary post the link as a reference. Moreover, the link may broke eventually, which would make your answer pointless.

Comment: The third command only appears to work with mapbox **tileLayers**, there is no `getContainer()` method for featuregroups

Comment: @RobertSiemer Good point! I think this is long-since superseded by the built-in functions indicated in the upper answers.

Answer (score 2):

Had to solve this recently, but stumbled upon this question.

Here is a solution that does not rely on CSS hacks and works with layer groups. It essentially removes and re-adds layers in the desired order.

I submit this as a better "best practice" than the current answer. It shows how to manage the layers and re-order them, which is also useful for other contexts. The current method uses the layer `Title` to identify which layer to re-order, but you can easily modify it to use an index or a reference to the actual layer object.

Improvements, comments, and edits are welcome and encouraged.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ob1h4uLm/

Or scroll down and click "Run code snippet" and play with it. I set the initial zoom level to a point that should help illustrate the `layerGroup` overlap effect.

```js
function LeafletHelper() {

    // Create the map
    var map = L.map('map').setView([39.5, -0.5], 4);

    // Set up the OSM layer
    var baseLayer = L.tileLayer(
        'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(map);

    var baseLayers = {
        "OSM tiles": baseLayer
    };

    this.map = map;

    this.BaseLayers = {
        "OSM tiles": baseLayer
    };
    this.LayersControl = L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);

    this.Overlays = [];
    this.AddOverlay = function (layerOptions, markers) {
        var zIndex = this.Overlays.length;
        var layerGroup = L.layerGroup(markers).addTo(map);
        this.LayersControl.addOverlay(layerGroup, layerOptions.title);
        this.Overlays.push({
            zIndex: zIndex,
            LeafletLayer: layerGroup,
            Options: layerOptions,
            InitialMarkers: markers,
            Title: layerOptions.title
        });
        return layerGroup;
    }
    this.RemoveOverlays = function () {
        for (var i = 0, len = this.Overlays.length; i < len; i++) {
            var layer = this.Overlays[i].LeafletLayer;
            this.map.removeLayer(layer);
            this.LayersControl.removeLayer(layer);
        }
        this.Overlays = [];
    }
    this.SetZIndexByTitle = function (title, zIndex) {

        var _this = this;

        // remove overlays, order them, and re-add in order
        var overlays = this.Overlays; // save reference
        this.RemoveOverlays();
        this.Overlays = overlays; // restore reference

        // filter overlays and set zIndex (may be multiple if dup title)
        overlays.forEach(function (item, idx, arr) {
            if (item.Title === title) {
                item.zIndex = zIndex;
            }
        });

        // sort by zIndex ASC
        overlays.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.zIndex - b.zIndex;
        });

        // re-add overlays to map and layers control
        overlays.forEach(function (item, idx, arr) {
            item.LeafletLayer.addTo(_this.map);
            _this.LayersControl.addOverlay(item.LeafletLayer, item.Title);
        });
    }
}

window.helper = new LeafletHelper();

AddOverlays = function () {
    // does not check for dups.. for simple example purposes only
    helper.AddOverlay({
        title: "Marker A"
    }, [L.marker([36.83711, -2.464459]).bindPopup("Marker A")]);
    helper.AddOverlay({
        title: "Marker B"
    }, [L.marker([36.83711, -3.464459]).bindPopup("Marker B")]);
    helper.AddOverlay({
        title: "Marker C"
    }, [L.marker([36.83711, -4.464459]).bindPopup("Marker c")]);
    helper.AddOverlay({
        title: "Marker D"
    }, [L.marker([36.83711, -5.464459]).bindPopup("Marker D")]);
}

AddOverlays();

var z = helper.Overlays.length;

ChangeZIndex = function () {
    helper.SetZIndexByTitle(helper.Overlays[0].Title, z++);
}

ChangeZIndexAnim = function () {
    StopAnim();
    var stuff = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
    var idx = 0;
    var ms = 200;
    window.tt = setInterval(function () {
        var title = "Marker " + stuff[idx++ % stuff.length];
        helper.SetZIndexByTitle(title, z++);
    }, ms);
}

StopAnim = function () {
    if (window.tt) clearInterval(window.tt);
}
```

```css
#map {
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<input type='button' value='Remove overlays' onclick='helper.RemoveOverlays();' />
<input type='button' value='Add overlays' onclick='AddOverlays();' />
<input type='button' value='Move bottom marker to top' onclick='ChangeZIndex();' />
<input type='button' value='Change z Index (Animated)' onclick='ChangeZIndexAnim();' />
<input type='button' value='Stop animation' onclick='StopAnim();' />
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found this fix (css):

```
.leaflet-map-pane {
    z-index: 2 !important;
}

.leaflet-google-layer {
    z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

found it here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44598/leaflet-google-map-baselayer-markers-not-visible